# How to draw a bent line with switch

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

This is somehow disappointing that latex doesn't have any simple remedy for this!

I want to draw an arrow between two points where there exists a switch in the middle of this arrow. For this I used this code:

```
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,0) to[cspst] (3,0);
```

This is almost okay but the switch in the middle is not very stylish. Is there any way to make it better?

And when I want to bend this line as follow:

```
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,-2) to[cspst,out=120,in=-20] (3,-2);
```

it causes the switch to disappear. Any solution?

This is an image for the results of the first and second code:

[image: d]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.8cm,text centered, line width=2pt ]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth,line width=2pt]
\tikzset{% define addarrow decoration
    addarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
                     postaction={decorate}}
                     }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,0) to[cspst] (3,0);
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,-2) to[cspst,out=-20,in=-120] (3,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've forgotten to include a class.

Comment: How is `addarrow` defined? Please test code before posting it!

Comment: @cfr Sorry. Thanks for your comment. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272124/54817

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,decorations} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning} 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.8cm,text centered, line width=2pt ]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth,line width=2pt]
\tikzset{addarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}} } 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,0) to[cspst] (3,0);
\draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,-2)  to[out=-20,in=-120] coordinate[pos=.35] (A) coordinate[pos=.55] (B) (3,-2) ; 
\fill[white] ( [yshift=-2mm] A) rectangle ( [yshift=1mm] B); 
\draw [line width=1pt] (A) to[cspst] (B);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the arrow is not there yet. It is a line.

Comment: This works: \draw [line width=1pt,addarrow] (0,0) to[cspst] (3,0);
\draw  [->,>=stealth,line width=1pt] (0,-2)  to[out=-20,in=-120] coordinate[pos=.30] (A) coordinate[pos=.40] (B) (3,-2) ; 
\fill[white] ( [yshift=-2mm] A) rectangle ( [yshift=1mm] B); 
\draw [line width=1pt] (A) to[cspst] (B);