# Problem is drawing a bent line with switch

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

This question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334923/how-to-draw-a-bent-line-with-switch).
I want to draw an arrow between two points where there exists a switch in the middle of this arrow. I followed the suggestion of above link, but the approach is not general and for each time, we have to play with the numbers there to get what we want. For example, consider this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,decorations} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning} 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.8cm,text centered, line width=2pt ]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth,line width=2pt]
\tikzset{addarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}} } 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (b) at (1,1)  {$A$};
\node (a) at (2.5,-1.9)  {$B$};
\draw  [->,>=stealth,line width=1pt] (a)  to[out=105,in=-50] coordinate[pos=.35] (A) coordinate[pos=.55] (B) (b) ; 
\fill[white] ( [yshift=-2mm] A) rectangle ( [yshift=1mm] B); 
\draw [line width=1pt] (A) to[cspst] (B); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows.[image]
As can be seen the switch is not completely connected to the line. How can we fix this? Why we have 0.35 and -2mm in the code (coordinate[pos=.35], [yshift=-2mm])?

Comment: I don't even understand this question  (or the other one). Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @daleif I don't know which part is not clear. I want to draw a bent line with arrow between two points but there is a switch in the middle of this line. This is useful to draw a circuit or model a binary link between two nodes (when the switch is on the link is available, otherwise, the link is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to improve the join between the switch and the line.  One is to add dots at the junction points.  Another is to reduce the radius of the fill circle by about half the line width.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,decorations} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,positioning} 
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.8cm,text centered, line width=2pt ]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth,line width=2pt]
\tikzset{addarrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{stealth}}}, postaction={decorate}} } 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (b) at (1,1)  {$A$};
\node (a) at (2.5,-1.9)  {$B$};
\draw  [->,>=stealth,line width=1pt] (a)  to[out=105,in=-50] coordinate[pos=.35] (A) coordinate[pos=.55] (B) (b) ; 
\fill[white] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n2={.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)-.25pt}
   in ($(A)!.5!(B)$) circle(\n2);
\draw [line width=.5pt] (A) to[cspst,*-*] (B);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]