# How to draw a simple 3 phase system in circuits TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits

I've been trying to draw a three phase system (star connection) with the help of circuits TikZ. I was able to draw a single phase system but as soon as I try to extend the system to three phase, different errors appear.

Does anyone have an example of such a circuit?

Thank you very much

Comment: please, show your one-phase system. and  provide a sketch, how should three-phase look like. by the way, exist a lot of 3-phase systems, what is your? a grid? a motor? ... welcome to tex.se!

Comment: It is a grid. Very simple 3 voltage sources and three loads star connected. Where can I find such examples? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Upload the minimal working example.

Comment: please, at least provide sketch! without showing what you try so far is unlikely that someone help you

Comment: Some helpful links for beginner: [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272038/bend-circuit-elements-in-tikz/272124?s=61|0.0577#272124 interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, many years has passed since I used schemes like this, so it might be that I don't remember correct. (It would help with a sketch;-). The center of the source is at `(Csource)` and the load `(Cload)`. I also put in some loads in between since I found a picture like that.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  %% Source
  \coordinate (Csource);
  \foreach \anch/\ang in {a/0,b/120,c/240}{%
    \draw (Csource) to[vsourcesin=$\angle \ang^\circ$,*-*] +({-\ang+90}:3) coordinate (S\anch) node[anchor={\ang}]{(S\anch)};
  }
  %% Load
  \coordinate (Cload)  at ($(Csource)+(10,0)$);
  \foreach \anch/\ang in {a/0,b/-120,c/-240}{%
    \draw (Cload) to[R=$R_{\anch}$,*-*] +({-\ang+90}:3) coordinate (L\anch) node[anchor={\ang}]{(L\anch)};
  }
  %% Connections
  \draw (Sa) -- +(0,1) to[R] ($(La)+(0,1)$) -- (La);
  \draw (Sb) to[R] (Lb);
  \draw (Sc) -- +(0,-2) to[R] ($(Lc)+(0,-2)$) -- (Lc);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]